# reactjs: omit param from the state

Tags: reactjs

I have a state like the below:

```
this.state = {
   test: {a:"value1",b:"value2"},
   checkbox:true
}
```

if checkbox is false then i want

```
this.state = {a:"value1"} i want to omit b:"value1"
```

I am trying:

```
let {b,...y} = this.state.test
```

I am expecting y should be `{a:"value1"}`

I get the below error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Unexpected token (760:19)

> {b, **...y**} = this.state.test

Comment: use this: [transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)

Comment: what is the mistake am i doing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use a Rest Spread operator, which requires an additional plugin. NPM install the following plugin

```
"babel-preset-stage-2"
```

Then setup your webpack config accordingly;

```
module : {
    loaders: [{
        test    : /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude : /node_modules/,
        loader  : 'babel-loader',
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
            plugins: ['transform-object-rest-spread']
        }
    }]
}
```

Since your comment shows you are doing this inline, the following code might help you. This executed correctly in the chrome devtools.

```
state = { test: { a:"value1", b:"value2"}, checkbox:true }
x = { b, ...state2} = state.test
```

using the following in the Chrome DevTools throws an error;

```
let { b, ...state3} = state.test
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'b' has already been declared
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: Presently i am not using npm. rather in am including the script files directly inside the html and all my script is inside the script tags